# Can players enchant items?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, crafting

I know that the DM can give you enchanted items, but can players spend gold and downtime to enchant their own?

Comment: We can only have one question in a question post, so I've removed the second question. (You're free to post it as its own question though.)

Comment: [many related questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdnd-5e%5D+magical+crafting+is%3Aquestion)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The DMG has rules for this, at pp. 128-129, "Crafting Magic Items." You'll have to work with your GM to work out the details. In short, you can (with the GM's say-so) spend gold, spell slots, and time to create magic items; the rarer/more powerful the item, the harder to craft.